# How to make a Chrome Extension for Facebook repeatedly execute?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first, very simple Google Chrome extension as a joke for a friend. I want it to replace instances of "like" with "give a $h1t" (I know this doesn't seem mature, but it's just for fun).

This is my Javascript function so far;

```
function giveASh!t(){
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("Like", "g"), "Give a sh!t");
}
```

As I understand it, that searches through the HTML replacing every instance of "Like" with my alternative. This works.

However, the issue I'm facing is when you scroll down through your news feed, newly generated content does not get altered, any new instances of "Like" are not modified.

I understand that this code is executed once the initial page has finished loading, and once it's executed it is not re-run.

I've played about with the setInterval() method, and that lead to some strange errors. I set it to an interval of 10 seconds, but it would affect the loading of other content on the page (such as the chat section), and also was not too nice as the page would 'stutter' as if undergoing a refresh. Eventually the page would break, and it was impossible to scroll down the newsfeed any further.

My main point is; how can I get this javascript to run continuously, in a nice way? Perhaps a better way would be to listen for scroll events, and then run the javascript?

Comment: This question has little to nothing to do with Facebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [livequery()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin for jQuery that allows you to update HTML as new divs get added to the DOM:

```
$("#<id of divs that get added>").livequery(function(){giveAShit();});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function giveASh!t(){
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp("Like", "g"), "Give a sh!t");
}
window.setInterval(giveASh!t, 1000);
```

Comment: **-1** Don't give `window.setInterval` a string!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I gave it a go. It had the same issue however. Eventually, Facebook gives up generating new content as you scroll down. I'm beginning to think it's the replace method I'm using. When I removed the .innerHTML Facebook itself doesn't break, although the "Like" instances don't change...